# POST params from VBA to PHP

Tags: php, vba, ms-access, post, http-post

I've an MS Access file that include some VBA and i'd like to make an http request in POST mode and with some parameters.

```
URL = "http://example.com/mypage.php"
params = "par1=value1&par2=value2"
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
With objHTTP
     .Open "POST", URL, False
     .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0"
     .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
     .send params
     response = .responseText
End With
```

And a .php page that try to print the POST params

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
print_r($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
?>
```

The only output that I receive from the PHP page is "array()" like no POST params is sent.

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Try testing your php page from another source such as Postman/Fiddler.  Or just `print` and not `print_r `

Comment: @TimWilliams From postman or other PHP page it works. From VBA no.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem.
My server have some internal redirect that lose the POST params from the VBA call (http to https). If I make the direct call (with https and www.) the system work.